# C error: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c

I wrote linked list on C.

```
#define MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH 256

struct node {
    char *value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *new_list() {
    struct node *head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->value = (char*) malloc(MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void add_node(struct node *head, char *value) {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *new_node;

    while(curr->next != 0) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    curr->next = new_node;
}

void delete_list(struct node* list) {
    struct node *curr = list;
    
    while (curr) {
        struct node* next = curr->next;
        free(curr->value);
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}

struct node *list = new_list();
add_node(list, "hello");
delete_list(list);
```

Compiler: GCC. Line `curr->next = new_node;` in `add_node` function causes an runtime error. Which leads to this error? How to fix it?

> Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400864
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: The error is trying to free the string-constant "hello". You could for example do `new_node->value = strdup (value);` in add_node.

Comment: It's also bad practice to compare a pointer to zero rather than null.  Null may very well be defined as zero, but using null is typical, semantically clear in addition to the defined mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `free` a pointer that was returned by `malloc`.

You are doing

```
free(curr->value);
```

when `curr->value` happens to point to the string literal `"hello"`, which was not allocated by `malloc`.

You could fix it by either:

- Allocating the value with `malloc` (or another function that uses `malloc`, such as `strdup`)
- Not `free`ing the value. (But if you have some values that need to be `free`d and some that don't, your program needs to remember which ones to `free`)